# List.Count Raises Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, list, unityscript

I'm creating a 2D spaceship game in Unity. I have an object titled "Player" with this script attached to it. In the script, I have this class representing the player's ship:

```
public class Ship : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Weapon> weaponsList;

    void Start()
    {
        weaponsList = new List<Weapon>();
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
    }
}
```

And this class (within the same script) representing a weapon:

```
public class Weapon
{
    //properties here
}
```

Now, when I try to reference weaponsList to get List.Count using this code (from a different script), it throws a NullReferenceException, saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object:

```
Ship ship = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Ship>();
if (ship.weaponsList.Count >=2)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But any other property of ship i try to access works just fine. Can someone help? If you need additional context or code, please let me know and I'll make the necessary edits.

**EDIT:** The start method is special to Unity and is always called by default when the script initializes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this error **Add constructor to your class**

```
public class Ship : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Ship()
    {
         weaponsList = new List<Weapon>();
    }
    public List<Weapon> weaponsList;

    void Start()
    {
        weaponsList = new List<Weapon>();
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I made an edit to the question stating that Unity always calls the Start() method when the script initializes before anything else, so I assumed it would work in the same fashion that a constructor would. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: That solution causes `weaponsList` to be initialized twice. If there was anything done with the `weaponsList` before calling the `Start()` method this would cause odd behaviors. Better remove the second initialization out of the `Start()` method and even better make sure `weaponsList` can only be initialized once and/or only internally within the `Ship` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your `weaponsList` is `null` if `Start()` isn't called ... or it becomes `null` at some point. Change the public variable to become a public property to deny external callers to change the internal list:

```
public class Ship : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Weapon> weaponsList { get; private set; }
    public Ship()
    {
        weaponsList = new List<Weapon>();
    }
    ...
}
```

This will likely create compiler errors in other parts of your application. These errors are probably the reason why `weaponsList` becomes `null`.

In terms of better coding practice some more suggestions to change the property to this:

```
public IList<IWeapon> Weapons { get; private set; }
```

- Change the `List` to an interface.
- Change the `Weapon` to an `IWeapon`.
- Use Pascal notation (`Weapons`, not `weapons`).
- Avoid types in names: `Weapons`, not `WeaponsList` (that it is a list is obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Ship does not contain weapons list.

You can avoid the exception with

```
Ship ship = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Ship>();
if (ship != null && ship.weaponsList != null && ship.weaponsList.Count >=2)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

¿Is the method  Start() been call?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the initialization of the weapons list in the `void Start()` put it in the constructor of the object.  Then when the ship is created, the weapons list will always be initialized with a zero count.  A constructor should always put the object in question into a valid state so it can be used.  Sometimes, programmers create Init() or Start() methods to defer expensive logic until a method actually needs it, but in this case I would definitely put that initialization in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The list is constructed when `Start()` is called. If `Start()` is not called before the list is accessed, your error will appear. My guess is that you are trying to access the list before `Start()` is called.

You should consider building a constructor for the `Ship` class and placing the initialization code there:

```
public class Ship : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public List<Weapon> weaponsList;

    public Ship()
    {
        weaponsList = new List<Weapon>();
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
        weaponsList.Add(new Weapon());
    }
}
```

This constructor will be called as soon as objects of the class are created, and you won't have to call a method explicitly to get the object's properties constructed.